# PHP ZipArchive: Finding the name of the zipped folder after unzipping

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am using the ZipArchive to unzip a zip file:

This file is a zipped up folder and i want to:

Make sure that the content consists of just a folder (obviously with files in side)
Get the name of the unzipped folder so i can then rename it if needs be?

But having trouble getting the folders name after the unzip? I know i could get the name of the zip file as most of the time when zipped it the same name but some people also change the zipped file name.

Answer (score 8):

If you know for sure there's only one dir in the zip you can just do this:

```
$dir = trim($zip->getNameIndex(0), '/');
```

Otherwise, you'll have to loop over all the files and somehow figure out which one of them is the one you want:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
    $entry = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply will give it ago, and i am expecting the user to upload just a folder and thats why i want to check as well cheers

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you

Comment: $zip->getNameIndex(0) gives first file of the directory, how can i get the name of the directory?